# How to verify HSTS is working as expected in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, hsts

Most of the documentation talks about adding config.force_ssl = true which provides HSTS to Rails application. Well, how can I make sure its working as expected? How can I test HSTS header is added for every request? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `curl -i` usually gives you the goods.

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl -I https://your_website.domain` or browser developer tools to view response headers. You're interested in the `Strict-Transport-Security` header:

```
curl -I https://www.ssllabs.com/
HTTP/2 200
date: Fri, 23 Apr 2021 15:25:17 GMT
server: Apache
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000                    <-- this one
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
x-frame-options: DENY
content-type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
content-language: en-US
content-length: 6587
set-cookie: ...
content-security-policy: ...
```